# Embedding of $\ell_2$ in $L^p([0,1])$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(g_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. complex Gaussian random variables on $[0,1].$ Then it is easy to see that the map $j:\ell_2\to L^p([0,1])$ defined as $je_n=[E(g_n^p)]^{\frac{1}{p}}g_n,n\geq 1$ is an isometry and $j(\ell_2)$ is a closed subset of $L^p([0,1])$ which is also  complemented. Let $P:L^p([0,1])\to j(\ell_2)$ be the projection map. Then what can be said about the norm of $P$ ?

Comment: When you claim that the closed span of the Gaussians is complemented in $L^p[0,1]$, doesn't this require $1<p<\infty$? That is, I seem to recall that for $p=1$ we have an uncomplemented subspace.

Comment: yes! Off course! Sorry I did not mentioned that.

Comment: @ Pietro Majer. I have edited the question. But as I mentioned in the question $j(\ell_2)$ is a closed and complemented subspace of $L^p([0,1]).$ Hence the existence of the bounded projection is clear. Thank you.

Comment: Think about why $\|g_1\|_p$  is an upper bound when $2<p<\infty$, then consult some standard text. I don't have mine where I am now but I think it is in Tomczak-Jaegermann's book or Wojtaszczyk's book; maybe also in Albiac-Kalton.

Comment: @Bill. Thank you Bill. I would look into that.  Thank you very much.